Number of periodic points of subshift of finite type
Let $(X, \sigma)\subset (\{0, 1, 2, 3\}^\mathbb{N},\sigma)$ be a subshift of finite type. Let $P_n$ be the set of $n$-periodic points. If $|P_n|=2^n$ for all $n\ge 1$, then it is true that $(X, \sigma)$ is conjugated to a full shift of two letters?

Do you mean if $|P_n|=2^n$?

Ornstein extended his result about Bernoulli shifts to weak Bernoulli shifts, which include mixing Markov shifts...

@Asaf Could you please give more details? How is it related to this question? Thanks.

The entropy of your shift is $\log 2$, the entropy of the full shift (with the Bernoulli measure) is $\log 2$. If by conjugation you mean a topological isomorphism rather than a measurable one, I am not sure about the answer, maybe it is in Smorodinsky's old works.

I believe @Asaf is talking about measurable isomorphism, while the question is, I think, about topological conjugacy

You can do something cheap and have symbols 2 and 3 only followed by 0; 0 and 1 can be followed by 0 and 1.. This is still a (reducible) shift of finite type, and it satisfies your conditions. This issue might be improved by asking for a 2-sided irreducible SFT

@ville salo has pointed out that I made an assumption about your question, that you were studying vertex shifts, where the SFT was given by a 0-1 matrix describing allowed transitions between vertices. A more general definition of SFT allows one to forbid longer sequences of vertices. Can you say more about what you had in mind?

If $A$ is the transition matrix, the number of periodic points is $\text{Tr}(A^n)$. If you conjugate the matrix to Jordan normal form, you can see $
\text{Tr}(A^n)$ is the sum of the $n$th powers of the eigenvalues, counted with algebraic multiplicity (including generalized eigenvalues). The only choice of eigenvalues with the correct sum are 2,0,0,0. So you require $A$ to be a 0,1-valued matrix that has a single eigenvalue of 2 and three eigenvalues of 0 (possibly in a non-trivial Jordan block).
If you take $A$ to be, for example
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0&0
\cr
1&1&0&0
\cr
1&0&0&0
\cr
1&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
you get a matrix with the correct number of periodic points, but for which the SFT is not topologically conjugate to the full shift on 2 symbols (because of the additional points starting with 2 and 3).
If you require the SFT to be two-sided, there are no points with 2's and 3's; and the two SFTs are conjugate. And any example is essentially of this type (possibly with some relabelling).

Thanks a lot. Could you explain a little more for the last paragraph? Do you mean if the SFT is supposed to be two-sided, then it is topological conjugate to full shift? How to show that " any example is essentially of this type "?

What I mean is that in the two-sided version, even though the symbols 2 and 3 are in the alphabet, they do not appear in the actual 2-sided points because 2 and 3 do not follow any other symbol in the alphabet. In this case, the 2-sided shift with the $4\times 4$ matrix is equal to the original 2-sided shift. The same will be true for any SFT with these properties: there will be exactly two symbols that appear in the 2-sided shift; and they can occur in arbitrary concatenations.

How to see all of this? The matrix is supposed to have an eigenvalue 2; and an eigenvalue 0 with algebraic multiplicity 3. This means the Jordan form of the matrix has a one-dimensional block with eigenvalue 2; and one of {three one-dimensional blocks with eigenvalue 0; a two-dimensional block with eigenvalue 0 and a one-dimensional block with eigenvalue 0; a three-dimensional block with eigenvalue 0}. Going through the cases is a bit painful, and I have to admit I have not written out full details (although I am quite confident in the outcome)

Quas are you saying there are just a few matrices with the correct number of periodic points? The 2-shift has a pretty large orbit under the automorphism group of the 4-shift, so I don't get how such a naive approach can work.

For example by a result of Boyle, Lind and Rudolph, we can find a subshift of finite type with the correct period counts whose language agrees with that of the 4-shift for the first 100 steps.

Oh, you seem to be restricting to vertex shifts. Then it might work but it's not the same question.
